# Geary Spelling Checker for Foreign Language

Tags: pantheon-mail, language

I was wondering if there is any way to get Geary to spell check in a foreign language.

elementary OS - Freya; Geary version - 0.10.0; User level - Rookie.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change (or disable) spell checker language in Pantheon Mail](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8768/5565)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change the spell checker language on Geary 0.10 (or 0.11).

But that should be available in Geary 0.12 when released.
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720335