# Change (or disable) spell checker language in Pantheon Mail

Tags: pantheon-mail, settings, language, internationalization

Is there a way to change the spell checking language in Pantheon Mail from English to German (or any other language for other users)?

If not, is there a way to disable spell checking for Pantheon Mail?

It's really hard to write a mail if all words have a red line underneath.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In short, there should be. Elementary's Mail is based on Geary, which [added support](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2016-June/msg01793.html) for changing spell check dictionaries in June 2016. The feature does not appear to have been ported to the elementary version. As an alternative, you can install and use Geary until elementary addresses the issue (`sudo apt install geary`).

I opened **[a feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-mail/+bug/1634257)** for the spell check dictionaries. Please subscribe to the ticket so you can help the devs test a fix, if one comes.

Comment: Allright thx. I subscripted on the feature request. Hope to see some changes there...